# Html5 Video Playing after Double time taping in Iphone

Tags: html, html5-video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have Jwplayer in my website but in Iphone I have issue that after taping on "Done" in native player video not playingg in single tap. Its playing after double time taping. So what is the issue here?

link is http://test5.social27.com/Welcome.aspx

Comment: Do you have the same issue after pressing done with a native <video> tag as well?